# content jumpng down in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Every time I add a new "select" in my right sidebar, the content area is jumping a row down. The content area should stay at the top. I have went through all my div tags, but I cannot see what is going wrong here?

I am apparently not allwoed to make an answer on what the solution was, so the solution was as following:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 rightsidebar pull-right"`>
```

---

HTML:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper bg-info">
            <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 bg-danger">
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                        <h4>Home</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 rightsidebar">
                        <h3>test</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="selectbuilding">Building</label>
                                  <select class="form-control input-sm" name="choosebuilding">
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <br/><hr>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="selectappartment">Appartment</label>
                                  <select class="form-control input-sm" name="chooseappartment">
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <br/><hr>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="selectpeople">People</label>
                                  <select class="form-control input-sm" name="choosepeople">
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- / rightsidebar -->

                        <div class="col-lg-1" id="throw_1" style="list-style:none; padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <div class="fixed-width-col border">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-success" id="content">Content</div>

                        <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_2" style="list-style:none; padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <div class="fixed-width-col street">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_3" style="list-style:none; padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <div class="fixed-width-col number">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_4" style="list-style:none; padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <div class="fixed-width-col border">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /Container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Page Content Wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
/* Backgroundcolor on right sidebar*/
.rightsidebar {
  background-color: black;
}


/* hrows.css */
.fixed-width-col{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.street {
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fe5606 0%, #fd9a00 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number {
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a4ed5 0%, #3acfd5 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.border {
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
#throw_1 {
  height: 500px; 
  font-size: 13px;
 }

#throw_2 { 
  height: 330px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

#throw_3 {
  height: 330px;
  font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

#throw_4 {
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Nobody has a clue? :-(

Comment: Because as the container div gets bigger, it pushes other divs below it on the page lower.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Should I put a new container some place?

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain if you haven't worked with HTML and the document flow before, but there's a big box that holds the home bar and your right shoulder bar. As the right shoulder bar gets bigger, it makes its holder box bigger, so everything below it pushes down.

Comment: I think I have a little bit knowledge on how to program, but thanks for the answer. I am just gonna wait until somebody have an idea how I could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap grid have 12 column total width. Your `<div class="col-lg-10 bg-danger">` goes together with `<div class="col-lg-2 rightsidebar">` which gives total 12. So next columns (`col-lg-1`,`col-lg-6`,`col-lg-1`,`col-lg-1`,`col-lg-1`) go to next row. I found 2 solutions:

1.add `float:right` to rightsidebar: `<div class="col-lg-2 rightsidebar" style="float:right">`

2.place content columns into `<div class="col-lg-10 bg-danger">`:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 bg-danger">
    <div class="col-lg-1" id="throw_1">
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```